# The minimal number of persons in ten photos

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Tom has ten photos. there are three persons in each photo: a man  in the middle of it, his son  is on the left of him and  his brother  is on the right.

There are 10 men in the middle of these 10 photos, and the 10 men are different from each other.

There are $n$ different persons in the $10$ photos. What is the minimal value of $n$  ?

---

I think,  $n\geqslant 16$ as follow. But I don't sure. Thank you!

$B_1$  and $B_2$ are brothers,  $S_1$ is son of $B_1$ and  $S_2$ is son of $B_2$.  $S_1$, $B_1, B_2$ are in the first photo, $S_2$, $B_2, B_1$ are in the second photo.

$S_2$  and $B_3$ are brothers,  $S_4$ is son of $S_2$ and  $S_3$ is son of $B_3$.  $S_4$, $S_2, B_3$ are in the third photo, $S_3$, $B_3, S_2$ are in the fourth photo.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you got to your answer?

Comment: Are the 10 photo different in the sense that the sets of persons on them are different?

Comment: person are different  in the sense of set of all persons